# ASP.NET CustomControl - RenderControl on a Attribute value

Tags: asp.net

I would like to add a attribute to a custom control to extend it's feature.

```
<ns:PasswordChange 
  runat="server" 
  ID="pwch" 
  UserId='<%# ResidentId %>' />
```

In the code ..

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:PasswordChange runat=server />")]
public class PasswordChange : WebControl
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
      writer.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
      writer.Write(script.Replace("{0}",***ajaxCall***));
      writer.Write("</script>");
    } 
    ......
```

The parameter ajaxCall above contain the result of the evaulated `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.UserId))`. That evaluation simply add one ajax-URL if there are a UserId, if not, another url.

The problem is that UserId isn't loaded at the time of RenderControl. It's not so surprising because this is the code that tells the user that UserId is an available attribute at all.

I would like some help/advice how I solve this kind of problem. The attribute is of course there for behavior of the control. I'm not superfamiliar with the execution-model of those controls.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding a `LiteralControl` during rendering, and populate it on `PreLoad` based on the value of `UserID`.

Comment: Thank's. Ok.. I die. Buggy phreaking programming! Look at the code snippet in my question, row 4. `<%# ResidentId %>' />`. Try `<%= ResidentId %>' />`. Time to end the day!

Comment: But I earned a lot more of the Custom Control, attributes and execution model..... So I think I'm happy ;p